# Problems drawing the real cursor

Tags: c#, bitmap, drawing, cursor

I'm developing a screeshot application. I'd like to catch the real cursor to draw it on a bitmap. 
 I have two implementation: in the former the cursor is displayed well, but it is always the default cursor; while in the latter the cursor sometimes is drawn well, and sometimes it isn't updated and well-drawn.
Is there any way to merge the positive aspects of these implementation?

First:

```
Point cursorPosition = Cursor.Position;
if (_bitmapRectangle.Contains(cursorPosition))
{
    Point relativeCursorPosition = new Point(cursorPosition.X - _bitmapRectangle.Location.X, cursorPosition.Y - _bitmapRectangle.Location.Y);
    Cursor.Draw(graphics, new Rectangle(relativeCursorPosition, Cursor.Size));
}
```

Second:

```
Point cursorPosition = Cursor.Position;
using (Cursor cursor = Cursor.Current)
{ 
   if (_bitmapRectangle.Contains(cursorPosition))
   {
       Point relativeCursorPosition = new Point(cursorPosition.X - _bitmapRectangle.Location.X, cursorPosition.Y - _bitmapRectangle.Location.Y);
       cursor.Draw(graphics, new Rectangle(relativeCursorPosition, cursor.Size));
    }
}
```

It seems that the second solution works bad when I'm not using the default cursor and when the mouse is on a background form (and the screenshot form is on the foreground).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Point cursorPosition = Cursor.Position;
if (_bitmapRectangle.Contains(cursorPosition))
{
    Point relativeCursorPosition = new Point(cursorPosition.X - _bitmapRectangle.Location.X, cursorPosition.Y - _bitmapRectangle.Location.Y);
    new Cursor (Cursor.Current.Handle).Draw(graphics, new Rectangle(relativeCursorPosition, Cursor.Size));
}
```

Comment: No, it catches the wrong cursor when I'm pointing something on a not-focused window

Comment: While I'm testing this code, it throws a NullReferenceException

Comment: I see... when not in focus it is quite possible that Cursor.Current.Handle is not valid... currently no new idea, sorry :-(